# WPF bind an ICommand parameter to another control's SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a `DataGrid` and a `Button` on the same hierarchy level. I need to pass the `DataGrid.SelectedItem` property to the `Button`'s `ICommand` parameter.

This is what I got:

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="MyListGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"
    Margin="10,10,10,10">
</DataGrid>

<Button Content="My Button" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Path=SelectedItem, ElementName=MyListGrid}" />
```

I'm getting an exception on `RelayCommand`1.CanExecute(Object parameter)`saying`parameter is null`. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**: Relay command implementation can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/Wqgk3k6d

Comment: What implementation of `RelayCommand` are you using? Does it throw an exception if `parameter` is null?  Because it should just return false in that case.

Comment: What does your CanExecute method do?

Comment: I'm using the implementation that comes with the Kinect SDK toolkit. I already compared it to the popular one found here in SO and in some other places and it is exactly the same, but it is documented. I'll update it.

Comment: Have you selected any items from the DataGrid, before pressing "My Button" ?

Comment: It cashes before the screen is actually shown, so I can't press the button without anything selected. The grid has 2 rows pre-loaded.